# How does one set useragent for phantomjs driver in clj-webdriver?

Tags: clojure, selenium-webdriver

I am using clojure with clj-webdriver like so:

```
(set-driver! {:browser :phantomjs} "url")
```

how do I set the useragent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For clj-webdriver 0.6.1 with PhantomJS support you can do this by setting capabilities

```
(ns site-test
  (:require [clj-webdriver.taxi :refer :all]
            [clj-webdriver.driver :refer [init-driver]])
  (:import (org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs PhantomJSDriver)
           (org.openqa.selenium.remote DesiredCapabilities)))

(System/setProperty "phantomjs.binary.path" "D:/Drivers/phantomjs-1.9.7-windows/phantomjs.exe")

(set-driver!
  (init-driver
      {:webdriver
        (PhantomJSDriver. (doto (DesiredCapabilities.)
                            (.setCapability "phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0")
                            (.setCapability "phantomjs.page.customHeaders.Accept-Language" "en-US")
                            (.setCapability "phantomjs.page.customHeaders.Connection" "keep-alive")
                            (.setCapability "phantomjs.cli.args" (into-array String ["--ignore-ssl-errors=true"
                                                                                     "--webdriver-loglevel=WARN"]))))}))
```